# IdentityServer4 External Authentication without cookies

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm having trouble understanding how ASP.NET Core authentication works.

I want to implement JWT access token authentication with refresh tokens. To my knowledge, this is the industry standard for authenticating a client (Mobile app, SPA Web application). For security purposes, I'd prefer to not implement my own authorization logic including JWT generation and refresh token handling. Since ASP.Net does not natively support this, Naturally my choice would be to use `IdentityServer4`, a large open source library for handling this kind of stuff.

However `IdentityServer4` is heavily based on OAuth, and I'm not sure how that works with SPA applications and mobile apps (clients I trust). It requires the client to redirect to some arbitrary webpage to enter their credentials and then redirect back to the app. Gross. I've never seen a major app like Snapchat, Instagram, etc. have this kind of authentication flow where you are directed to some webpage/browser during the login flow. Luckily `IdentityServer4` has a little feature to handle username/password authentication for my trusted clients (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html)

Great, that seems to suit my needs. But... Now I want to add Facebook Authentication. `IdentityServer4` allows for [External Authentication](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html), however it is still cookie based (to my knowledge). Which requires the Android/iOS/SPA app to redirect to a webpage and then redirect back to the app. Again, this isn't ideal from a user perspective. Facebook provides native mobile SDKs to handle this type of authentication which returns an access token so there is no need to redirect to web pages using cookies.

Now lets say my iOS app uses the Facebook SDK to grab an access token for the user and sends it to the backend. The backend validates the token against the Facebook SDK, and subsequently registers a local user in it's own database.

Now when that same iOS user tries to login to the app, the app will generate a facebook access token for that user from the SDK and send it to the backend. However I'm not sure how to utilize `IdentityServer4` to generate a JWT for the user since I need that users' username and password. This is where I'm stuck. I seem to be fighting against the library which makes me believe I am severely misunderstanding something.

TLDR; `IdentityServer4` seems to be heavily based on cookies which doesn't really fit nicely into mobile apps/SPA webpages when you are redirected back and forth from authentication webpages. Am I using the wrong tool for the job? What are some alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1):

As a note on big social apps: I think it comes down to who keeps the passwords. Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat, Google act as identity providers to third parties. They themselves require user to register and specify the password which they keep. Therefore they can use any customized approach for handling validation with those passwords. However, if any of them offerred a posibiltty to log-in with the other I.e Instagram were allowing to sign-in with Amazon credentials, then they would need to follow through a standard way like OAuth and redirect to the third party for log-in. Last time I checked Instagram, Facebook and Snapchat only offer to register and no option to sign in with 3rd parties which explains why the don't need redirects.

Now if we establish that a redirect is a necessary evil, then the means to carry over the data accross aren't that numerous. I.e. we either would need to pass data via a query string or use cookies. Am I missing any others?

Both have limitations but since cookies are persisted and browser carries them automatically with each request, they do seem like a better option for the job, especially if multiple redirects are required for an external IdP to track the state of authentication request. The same reason is mentioned here:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely the right tool for the job if you want what OpenID Connect and OAuth2 give you. It sounds like you may need convincing though and it may be that your use case doesn't need the full breadth of functionality offered.

If you have multiple client applications and APIs in play then I think using OpenID Connect and `IdentityServer4` the right choice at this point in time.

Regarding native apps, you used to word "gross" to describe using the user's default browser to perform the sign in process and it's understandable why you might think that at first but it's not as bad of a UX as you'd think and has plenty of advantages:

1. The client application is completely decoupled from how authentication is actually done be that federation, social sign in (Facebook in your case), multi-factor, retina scan etc. Your identity server deals with all that complexity and is a single point of management (and failure - so make it highly available!)
2. Single sign on is possible - if they're already signed into your IDP then they can go straight in (although you have full control of the flow - want them to consent or confirm the sign in request every time - you can do that)
3. If the user has a password manager set up in their browser then that'll work too

Both iOS and Android offer APIs for doing this stuff and the work well. If you skin your native and web UIs to look similar the flow from a user's PoV is not jarring at all.

You can still use refresh tokens (ultimately secured by the platform) so you don't actually have to do the interactive flow very often anyway.

Some additional reading below. Quite a lot of thinking has gone into this from the industry so it's definitely worth digesting the current best practice.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

IETF current best practice: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252

Don't make Scott hate you ;) : https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

For client side SPA browser apps OIDC provides the implicit grant type and uses a silent refresh and IDP session monitoring mechanism to maintain the session. Check out the `oidc-client-js` library which implements this approach.

Comment: You mention "but it's not as bad of a UX as you'd think and has plenty of advantages". Personally, I don't mind the browser flow, but when I look at huge apps like instagram, snapchat, facebook, etc None of these redirect to the browser first. You say its "best practice", but none of the major apps redirect to a browser, so that's what I'm failing to understand. How do these guys do it?

Comment: I can't really speak for big social apps as I'm coming from this from a business application PoV and all the requirements that come with that. As for *how* they do it - likely they home roll stuff using platform capabilities - possibly using something resembling a refresh token under the hood.